# Hide or alter id in url in php

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I am looking to hide the order id in URL. details.php?id=492. Is it possible to hide it or just alter it? Because anyone can check the details of other orders by changing the count. I tried few answers given in similar posts by adding data to htaccess but no avail. Thanks in advance.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^details/$ details.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ details.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ details.php?id=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/?$    details.php?id=$1     [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect /index?id=2 to /index/2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+details\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /details/%1? [R=302,L]

#Internally forward /index/2 to /index.php?id=2
RewriteRule ^order_details/([0-9]+)/?$ /order_details.php?o_id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Its not possible to totally hide id reference, with URL rewrite even you can change pattern URL but you will need this ID ref. somewhere in URL and reason behind is that you will fetch and use that id to get information on page.

An alternative you can do is, rather than id you may use another field and fetch data by that field value say for an eg. product name then url would be something like details.php?name=abc which you may rewrite later as details/$1 OR as per your need

Comment: Alright! Thanks Rupal... Let me try that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Encryption method like :

```
$myData = array('id'=>164);
$encrypt_data = base64_encode(json_encode($myData) );
```

and add this on URL

```
details.php?secret=$encrypt_data
```

and back on in details page

```
$myData = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['secret'] ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. so I should add the above two lines in php code and second in URL. but why 164? Let me try this.

Comment: I just gave example with "164" you can add more key as well as per your need. @stackkid